# read.csv() with UTF-8 encoding

Tags: r, utf-8, read.csv

I am trying to read in data from a csv file and specify the encoding of the characters to be UTF-8. From reading through the ?read.csv() instructions, it seems that fileEncoding set equal to UTF-8 should accomplish this, however, I am not seeing that when checking. Is there a better way to specify the encoding of character strings to be UTF-8 when importing the data?

Sample Data:

[Download Sample Data here](https://spaces.hightail.com/space/pwWp9)

```
fruit<- read.csv("fruit.csv", header = TRUE, fileEncoding = "UTF-8")
fruit[] <- lapply(fruit, as.character)
Encoding(fruit$Fruit)
```

The output is "uknown" but I would expect this to be "UTF-8". What is the best way to ensure all imported characters are UTF-8? Thank you.

Comment: Tried using the `encoding` argument instead?

Comment: What was the class before you forced conversion to `as.character`? Maybe add `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` to `read.csv`. Also, if non of your characters are outside the ASCII range, it won't bother with the encoding: `x<-"Hello"; Encoding(x)<-"UTF-8"; Encoding(x)` vs `x<-"Həllö"; Encoding(x)`

Answer (score 8):

```
fruit       <- read.csv("fruit.csv", header = TRUE)
fruit[]     <- lapply(fruit, as.character)
fruit$Fruit <- paste0(fruit$Fruit, "\xfcmlaut") # Get non-ASCII char and jam it in!
Encoding(fruit$Fruit)
```

> [1] "latin1" "latin1" "latin1"

```
fruit$Fruit <- enc2utf8(fruit$Fruit)
Encoding(fruit$Fruit)
```

> [1] "UTF-8" "UTF-8" "UTF-8"